# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable in matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have this error:

> "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

This is the part of the code that displays the error:

```
nd_coord = random.uniform(npoints, 2)         
nd_coord[:,0] = nd_coord[:,0] * ((xmax - xmin) + xmin)   
nd_coord[:,1] = nd_coord[:,1] * ((ymax - ymin) + ymin)  
print (nd_coord)
```

Comment: Have you printed `nd_coord`, or checked it's type and/or shape?  Clearly it isn't the 2d array that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you've imported NumPy as `from numpy import *` and so `random.uniform` is the NumPy method. Its [call signature](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) is:

> numpy.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None)

So the way you're using it, it returns a single number (which can't be indexed). Perhaps you want:

```
nd_coord = np.random.uniform(size=(npoints,2))
```

To pick `npoints` pairs of random numbers on [0,1).